# Apache not working with Linux ACL

Tags: apache-2.2, access-control-list

I'm having a big problem with Apache and ACL. I have two servers, both running CentOS 6.3, but the first one is running CPanel/WHM and the second one is just Apache, ACL and Samba for local sharing.

In the first box (the one with CPanel), I have a folder called `/test` and the owner of this folder is `abc`. My Apache is running as user `nobody`. If I try to create a directory or file (using PHP, for example), I can't. If I add the user `nobody` to the ACL list (`setfacl -Rm u:nobody:rwx /test`), now I *can* write to this folder, even if owner is still `abc`.

The same scenario doesn't work on second box, with standard Apache (not compiled by CPanel), and I can't figure out why. I have my filesystem mounted with ACL on both machines. I'm using ACL with Samba in the second box without any problem, so it's not an ACL problem itself.

If I change the owner of `/test` to `nobody`, now I can modify that directory with PHP scripts. I just can't use ACL on that second box.

Comment: Does the second one have apparmor or selinux or some other alternate security system?

Comment: +1 CentOS has SELinux out of the box which if enabled [getsestatus] will stop httpd from writing to anything outside of /var/www unless you change the context of the directories. [semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/test(/.*)?"] then [restorecon -Rv /test]

Comment: unfortunately, still not working. SE linux is already disabled. [code][root@teste html]# getenforce
Disabled
[/code]